# Turn column values into columns counting occurrences based on row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that stores `job_name` in a column and `resolved_by` in another column. Resolvers can solve the same problem multiple times. I want to output a table that counts how many times each resolver has solved a problem even if they never solved one which in that case should be 0. Heres my current table.

[image: Current Table]

Right now I have tried a double group by to give me the count of how many times each person has solved a specific problem they already solved but it doesn't show that a person hasn't solved a problem.

```
SELECT job_name, resolved_by, COUNT(*) FROM tb GROUP BY job_name, resolved_by ORDER BY job_name, resolved_by;
```

[image: Double Group by]

Im looking for a table that has `resolved_by` as a column and each `job_name` as a column where the count of how many times each person has solved that 'job_name' is filled in including zeroes for where they didn't resolve that specific 'job_name' or a table similar to the one that I tried except having that also include jobs that each person hasn't solved with 0 as the count.

Desired table:

[image: Desired Table]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: added desired results

Answer (score 0):

You need a list of people to start with.  So, something like this:

```
SELECT p.person_id, COUNT(tb.resolved_by)
FROM people p LEFT JOIN
     tb
     ON p.person_id = tb.resolved_by
GROUP BY p.person_id;
```

Comment: Im confused what is p.person_id? Shouldn't I be dealing with job_name somewhere in this and not looking at the resolvers twice? I added some pictures to my question

Comment: I tried this and it gives me the total number of problems that each person has solved. I use this select p.resolved_by, count(tb.resolved_by) from (SELECT distinct resolved_by FROM tb) p left join tb on p.resolved_by = tb.resolved_by group by p.resolved_by;